# Find out the minimum packaging of a product for an order

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm making an app that sells packaged products. For example, product A has packs of 3 and 5 units.

Given an order from a customer I have to return the number of packages that are necessary to satisfy the customer's order, **minimizing** the number of packages.

For example, Products:

PN: packs of 3 and 5 elements.
     TS: packs of 2, 5 and 8 elements

Customer order (**input**): 10 PN and 14 TS.

Expected **output**:

10 PN:

- 2 * 5 (two packs of 5 elements)

14 TS:

- 1 * 8 (a pack of 8 elements)
- 3 * 2 (three packs of 2 elements)

Any ideas for an algorithm that can help me solve the problem?

Edit:

My solution:

```
    if(amount > qty)
        return;

    if(qty == amount){ //found a possibility
        if(countPacks < minPacks) {
            minPacks = countPacks;
            solution = Arrays.copyOf(counters, counters.length);
            totalPrice = price;
        }
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < counters.length ; i++) {
        amount = amount + packs.get(i).getQuantity();
        counters[i] = counters[i] + 1;
        countPacks = countPacks + 1;
        price = price + packs.get(i).getPrice();

        findMinPacks(packs, qty, amount, counters, countPacks, price);

        counters[i] = counters[i] - 1;
        countPacks = countPacks - 1;
        amount = amount - packs.get(i).getQuantity();
        price = price - packs.get(i).getPrice();
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- The first thing that you have to do is to determine the nature of product ( PN or TS )
- Using the type of product , you already know the types of packages that you have
- Due to the given number , you ll calculate the needed number of packages on each type , then you can compare the numbers and return the minimum

**Example :**

*Input : 10PN*

*Determine nature of product : PN*

*Determine possibilities of packages : pack of 3 & pack of 5*

*Calculate all possibilities of combinations of pack's types to satisfy the given number on input => [ (1 pack of 3) : false , (2 pack of 3) : false , (1 pack of 3) and (1 pack of 5) : false ........ (2 pack of 5) : true ..... etc ]*

*Get all those possibilities with true and return the one with the minimum of packages number [ in this case its (2 pack of 5) ]*

Comment: How can i get all the packaging combinations? Thanks for the answer

Comment: You can do something like this , for example you need 10 and you have packs of 3 and 5 , at first you will see if 1 po3 + 0 po5 = 10? , then if 1 po3 + 1 po5 = 10 ? , 2 po3 + 1 po5 = 10 ? .... etc you keep playing with the possibilities of numbers @user2989745

Comment: Hello,  even with the pseudocode I am not able to come up with a solution. I edited the post with a greedy solution that doesn't fit. Can you help me with code?